# Why are there two instances created of a singleton Java class?

Tags: java, android, class, static-initialization

I have gone through some related topics on internet like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) and questions here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26699511), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910658) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54431660), but I'm getting nowhere. Here is my simplified code:

**MainActivity**:

```
package com.test.staticvariables;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Test1 test1 = Test1.getInstance();
    // do something
    Test2.printTest1Instances();
  }
}
```

**Test1**:

```
package com.test.staticvariables;

public class Test1 {

  private static Test1 test1;

  static {
    System.out.println("Initializing Test1, loader: " + " " + Test1.class.getClassLoader());
  }

  static synchronized Test1 getInstance() {
    if (test1 == null) {
      test1 = new Test1();
    }
    return test1;
  }

  private Test1() {}
}
```

**Test2**:

```
package com.test.staticvariables;

public class Test2 {

  private static final Test1 test1;
  // private static final Test1 test1 = Test1.getInstance();
  // private static final Test1 test1 = getTest1Instance();

  static {
    System.out.println("Initializing Test2, loader: " + " " + Test2.class.getClassLoader());
    test1 = Test1.getInstance();
  }

  static Test1 getTest1Instance() {
    return Test1.getInstance();
  }

  private Test2() {}

  static void printTest1Instances() {
    System.out.println("Test1 class variable: " + test1);
    System.out.println("Test1 instance variable: " + Test1.getInstance());
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Initializing Test1, loader: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList...]
Initializing Test2, loader: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList...]
Test1 class variable: com.test.staticvariables.Test1@2a7bfa4
Test1 instance variable: com.test.staticvariables.Test1@7e2a464
```

Why are two instances created of class `Test1` (`2a7bfa4` and `7e2a464`)?

Please note that `Test2` only contains static methods, it's not being instantiated.

The app runs in a single native process, so the classes should be loaded by the same class loader (if I understand it correctly).

Declaring and initializing (inside or outside a static method or a static initialization block) a final static variable holding other class instance is a wrong / bad practice? Or is it wrong under certain situations?

Comment: I don't know about you, but it works alright for me, only thing is, I would modify your `getInstance()` method.

Comment: probably this is a memory visiblility issue. Try making Test1.test1 volatile.

Comment: Do you have multiple class loaders involved? If so, you should explain that in your Question.

Comment: so what's the answer?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch I refactored the classes to use enums, dependency injection etc. and didn't investigate further.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like very interesting question. I have run the same project but directly from public static void main and it returned the expected good results. Nothing broken.[image: working well]

So it must have to do with android and how classes are loaded on your project.

Answer (score 1):

## No problem here

I wrote similar code in plain Java rather than Android. I chose a theme of [Gilligan’s Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilligan%27s_Island) to be less confusing than `Test1/2`.

Seems to run properly.

First, the singleton class, `Gilligan`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Gilligan
{
    private static Gilligan gilligan;  // Hold a singleton.

    static
    {
        System.out.println( "Static class loading of Gilligan, loader: " + " " + Gilligan.class.getClassLoader() + " at " + Instant.now() );
    }

    static synchronized Gilligan getInstance ( )
    {
        // Lazy loading of our singleton, an instance of `Gilligan`.
        if ( gilligan == null )
        {
            gilligan = new Gilligan();
        }
        return gilligan;
    }

    // Constructor - private
    private Gilligan ( ) {}
}
```

The second class is `Island`, holding a static reference to the same singleton of `Gilligan`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;

public class Island
{
    private static final Gilligan gilligan;

    static
    {
        System.out.println( "Static class loading of Island, loader: " + " " + Island.class.getClassLoader() + " at " + Instant.now() );
        gilligan = Gilligan.getInstance();
    }

    // Constructor - private
    private Island ( ) {}

    static void proveSingleton ( )
    {

        boolean isSingleton = ( Island.gilligan == Gilligan.getInstance() );
        System.out.println( "Island.gilligan: " + gilligan );
        System.out.println( "Gilligan.gilligan: " + Gilligan.getInstance() );
        System.out.println( "Gilligan is a singleton: " + isSingleton );
    }
}
```

Lastly, an app to run that code, in a class named `Solo`.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public class Solo
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Gilligan g = Gilligan.getInstance();
        Island.proveSingleton();
    }
}
```

When run:

```
Static class loading of Gilligan, loader:  jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 at 2020-12-13T00:10:13.009691Z
Static class loading of Island, loader:  jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 at 2020-12-13T00:10:13.028805Z
Island.gilligan: work.basil.example.Gilligan@4c873330
Gilligan.gilligan: work.basil.example.Gilligan@4c873330
Gilligan is a singleton: true
```

## `volatile`

As someone commented, you may be seeing a cache memory visibility problem. If so, marking your singleton var with `volatile` might be called for.

If not familiar with that keyword and this issue, and you are using threads, study up on the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model). Read and re-read [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Goetz-Java-Concurrency-in-Practice/PGM68418.html) by Brian Goetz et al.

And you might consider implementing your singleton differently.

## Multiple class loaders

Is your app running with multiple class loaders involved? If so, edit your Question to explain. And see the Question, [*Singleton class with several different classloaders*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15156840/642706).

## Use `Enum` for singleton

I believe consensus in the Java world says that using the simple but powerful [enum facility in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is the best and safest way to implement a singleton.

```java
package work.basil.example;

enum Gilligan
{
    INSTANCE;
}
```

To access the instance, use `Gilligan.INSTANCE` rather than calling a getter method.

And there is **no need to store a static reference to the singleton on your second class**. Simply use `Gilligan.INSTANCE` in your code wherever you need access to the singleton.

Caveat: Using an enum for your singleton does *not* solve the problem of multiple class loaders at runtime.

See: [*Implementing Singleton with an Enum (in Java)*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26285520/642706)

I will skip the usual cautions about how use of a singleton is sometimes masking poor OOP design, and may make testing difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm aware of the `volatile` phenomenon and concurrency, though not an expert. A few weeks back I spent almost a whole night playing with this b/c I thought I was missing something very simple. Then I changed my code to instantiate the class inside methods and not to use the class variable. But I couldn't get an answer to the strange behavior. As for class loader, I'm not very sure about this. I didn't touch this area except what DVM's default behavior is. I'll spend some more time investigating this.